# Based on sizeof operator

Tags: c, gcc, casting, type-conversion

Why is this code printing 8 as its output when executing in gcc compiler?

```
#include<stdio.h>
double i;
int main()
{
(int)(float)(char)i;
printf("%d",sizeof(i));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because your program invokes unefined behavior.

Comment: Did you think about trying `sizeof((int)(float)(char)i)`? But that would be the same as `sizeof((int)i)`.

Comment: Because casting `i` doesn't change `i`'s type.

Comment: I tried it sizeof((int)(float)(char)i) and got 4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the type of `i`  is `double`, and the size of `double` on your platform is 8.

The line of weird casts doesn't matter, it doesn't change the declaration of `i`, nor the `sizeof` invocation.

Comment: so even if I cast it with any type it only returns the original declared type size...am I right?

Comment: but when i tried 'code' printf("%d",sizeof((int)(float)(char)i));  and i got the value as 4.

Comment: A cast is just an operation that produces a value. It doesn't mutate its operand. The statement `(int)i;` retrieves the value of `i`, converts it to an `int`, and then thows the result away. Just like `i+1;` or even `i;` it's a statement with no effect (which your compiler will hopefully warn you about if you ask). And by the way, you should use `%zu` to print the result of `sizeof`, or cast it ton an `int` to make it match `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

Typecasting can never reduce or increase the size of a variable.